# Page-object method to get an element location

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I need to get an element coordinates(location) using cooresponding page-object method.
Now I'm using the following method to get it:

```
- myelementname_element.wd.location[0] --> to get X
- myelementname_element.wd.location[1] --> to get Y
```

But I'm constantly getting the following warning:

**DEPRECATION WARNING**

> - You are calling a method named wd at d:/JenkinsWorkspace/jenkins/...
> - This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
> - This feature will be removed in the near future.
> - Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.

Could you please help me and provide me with corresponding page-object method?

TIA,
ANNA

Comment: strange  'wd'  is just an alias for '.driver'  and as far as I can tell from the Rdoc, page-object has no method for either.  It would seem what you are doing is pretty much correct, in that you are expecting it to pass through to webdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use methods supported by watir-webdriver (or selenium-webdriver) elements, but not directly supported by the page-object-gem elements, you need to first get the native element. This is done by calling the `element` method for the page-object-gem element:

```
myelementname_element.element
```

As you can see, you can get the three different gem element classes by doing:

```
puts page.myelementname_element.class
#=> PageObject::Elements::TextField

puts page.myelementname_element.element.class
#=> Watir::TextField

puts page.myelementname_element.element.wd.class
#=> Selenium::WebDriver::Element
```

For your specific example, you want to do:

```
myelementname_element.element.wd.location[0]
myelementname_element.element.wd.location[1]
```